# How to install libssl-dev for OpenSSL 1.0.2a version on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssl, ubuntu-14.04, libssl

The command `apt-cache policy libssl-dev` shows the following output:

```
libssl-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.11
  Version table:
     1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.11 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.0.1f-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

And when I install it via `apt-get install libssl-dev` get `1.0.1f` version. But I've installed the latest `openssl-1.0.2a` from source code by the following command:

```
wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2a.tar.gz
tar -xvzf openssl-1.0.2a.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.2a
./config --prefix=/usr/   
make
sudo make install
```

How could I install `libssl-dev-1.0.2a` version to be compatible with my `openssl-1.0.2a`?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: *"How could I install libssl-dev for OpenSSL 1.0.2a"* - the short answer is you can't because Ubuntu does not provide it. You might be able to find a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) that offers it. Or maybe your question is really [How do I create a PPA](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA)???